# wordpress: how is the default category "uncategorized" inserted by default in the database

Tags: wordpress

I am running a php cli script to pro grammatically post to a WordPress blog using  WordPress 3.2.1 and using only MySQL to do so. I bumped into a mystery. Even when I insert a post touching only the *_posts table, a new entry is created to *_terms_relationships. How is that done? Is there some kind of MySQL procedure somewhere to automatically do that?

My script to insert a new post

`INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_title,post_content,post_name,post_date,post_date_gmt,post_modified,post_modified_gmt,post_author,post_status) VALUES (:title,:post,'post_name',now(),now(),now(),now(),1,'publish')`

how come this queries provokes a new row to be inserted in *_terms_relationships?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a trigger included with the default Wordpress install (I just checked), maybe it's updated on a cron run?

Comment: Thanks, I've spotted the error in the code. It was another library I was using that was triggering that